# how I can make two index inequal in ampl?

Tags: linear-programming, ampl, glpk

I know if I want to make 2 index inequal in ampl I have to use the following term:

```
s.t. b2{s in S, p in P1, j in D1, i in P1, k in D1, r in R:p!=i}
```

But if I have to make also j!=k what I have to do?
I tried the following options but non of them worked!

```
s.t. b2{s in S, p in P1, j in D1, i in P1, k in D1, r in R:p!=i , j!=k}

s.t. b2{s in S, p in P1, j in D1, i in P1, k in D1, r in R:p!=i : j!=k}

s.t. b2{s in S, p in P1, j in D1, i in P1, k in D1, r in R:p!=i  j!=k}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `and`:

```
b2{s in S, p in P1, j in D1, i in P1, k in D1, r in R : p!=i and j!=k}
```